# How can I add a Django constraint that limits the number of foreign keys based on a column value?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Consider the following code:

(Using Python 3.7 and Django 2.2)

```py
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.db import models


class Parent(models.Model):
    limit = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

Is it possible to add a `CheckConstraint` such that the number of allowed Child's for each Parent is limited by the `limit` field on the `Parent`. For example something like the following on the `Parent` table:

```
models.CheckConstraint(
    check=models.Q(limit__gte=models.Count('children')),
    name='children_limit',
)
```

But this fails with

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query
```

To clarify: I would really prefer to do this a database constraint, I know how to do it in Python land.

Comment: Constraints are done in the database, if the engine supports it. What isn't working?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the error I get when I try to use that constraint.

Comment: Yeah, I was suspecting that. If your goal is integrity then I can only suggest making this a many to many with a through model, where you put the check constraint and the limit field in the through model. Untested, but I can't come with anything better that would be enforced at the database level.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/) on the Child model like this:

```
def restrict_amount(value):
    parent = Parent.objects.filter(pk=value).get()
    if parent.children.count() >= parent.limit:
        raise ValidationError(f'Parent already has maximal amount of children ({parent.limit})')


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children', validators=(restrict_amount, ))
```

Comment: Validators are handled in Django (python) not in the database.

Comment: You will get a lot of problems with race conditions when using this solution.